# Spark/Scala - Project runs fine from IntelliJ but throws error with SBT

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I have a Spark project that I'm running locally in IntelliJ and is working fine when I run from there. The project is very simple and just a toy example for the moment. Below is the code:

```
package mls.main


import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SQLContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}
import scala.io.Source


object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger
    import org.apache.log4j.Level
    print("HELLO WORLD!")
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.WARN)

    // fire up spark
    val sc = createContext
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    loadAHSData(List("x"),sqlContext)

  }

  def loadAHSData(years: List[String], sqlContext : SQLContext) : Unit = {
    // load the column names that exists in all 3 datasets
    val columns = sqlContext.sparkContext
      .textFile("data/common_columns.txt")
      .collect()
      .toSeq

    columns.foreach(println)
  }


  def createContext(appName: String, masterUrl: String): SparkContext = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(masterUrl)
    new SparkContext(conf)
  }

  def createContext(appName: String): SparkContext = createContext(appName, "local")

  def createContext: SparkContext = createContext("Data Application", "local")
}
```

When I run via IntelliJ, I get the proper output with a couple of columns from the specified text file. However, when `cd` into the proper directory and then run `sbt run` I see the "HELLO WORLD!" output, but it then fails with the below stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.None$
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at 

org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1826)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

17/12/13 09:52:14 WARN FileSystem: exception in the cleaner thread but it will continue to run
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics$StatisticsDataReferenceCleaner.run(FileSystem.java:2989)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17/12/13 09:52:14 ERROR Utils: uncaught error in thread SparkListenerBus, stopping SparkContext
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:312)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1279)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1.run(LiveListenerBus.scala:77)
17/12/13 09:52:14 ERROR Utils: throw uncaught fatal error in thread SparkListenerBus
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:312)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1279)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1.run(LiveListenerBus.scala:77)
17/12/13 09:52:14 ERROR ContextCleaner: Error in cleaning thread
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply$mcV$sp(ContextCleaner.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1279)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning(ContextCleaner.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anon$1.run(ContextCleaner.scala:73)
```

And my build.sbt looks like:

```
name := "MLS_scala"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
)

val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion
)
```

I cannot figure out why it works perfectly from IntelliJ, but gets that error from sbt. Please let me know if there are any steps I can do to fix this. Thank you!

Comment: What's the version of sbt? Do you have `project/build.properties` file? What's inside?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could be something to do with scala lib versioning, try adding this to your build.sbt:

```
fork := true
```

Or, to apply to only plain running:

```
fork in run := true
```

Comment: This works but can someone please explain a bit more?

Comment: @Thusitha it means that sbt runs your application in a separate JVM, not inside the one that runs sbt itself which is the default behavior. With a framework like Spark that pushes JVM tweaking to the limit, it is easy to see how this avoids some trouble. If I'm not sufficiently accurate, see also e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44298847/why-do-we-need-to-add-fork-in-run-true-when-running-spark-sbt-application).

Answer (score -2):

You must compile the project using SBT first before run it, use `sbt compile` and make sure the project is successfully built using SBT before `sbt run`, a guide link [https://alvinalexander.com/scala/sbt-how-to-compile-run-package-scala-project](http://How%20to%20compile,%20run,%20and%20package%20a%20Scala%20project%20with%20SBT)